# Store ListViewItem to a bat file?

Tags: c#, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, file-io, cmd

I am making a software that uses the folder path in listView and makes a .bat file that hides that folder on execution !

Here is the button that create the bat file:

```
private void HideItBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] strArray = new string[500];
    int i = 0;
    StreamWriter hide = new StreamWriter(HideNameTxt.Text + ".bat");
    hide.WriteLine("@Echo off");
    foreach (var cur in FolderList.Items)
    {
        strArray[i] = cur.ToString();
        hide.WriteLine("attrib " + strArray[i] + " +s +h");
        i++;
    }
     hide.Close();
}
```

Its nothing fancy i just put all the listView item in a string and used a loop t write a .bat file !

Here is the output (.bat file that is created) :

```
@Echo off
attrib ListViewItem: {C:\Users\Sand\Desktop\New folder} +s +h
```

Now the problem is that when i write the listViewIrem its format is ListViewItem: {item}
and this way the .bat file wont work ! so is there any way to remove 'ListViewItem: {}' from the output ! and just write the path of folder instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on the items' type. You are calling the `ToString()` method for each item. if all your items are type of `ListViewItem`, you might want to call the `.Text` property.

```
strArray[i] = ((ListViewItem)cur).Text;
```

or

```
foreach (ListViewItem cur in FolderList.Items)
{
    strArray[i] = cur.Text;
    hide.WriteLine("attrib " + strArray[i] + " +s +h");
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `Text` property:

```
strArray[i] = cur.Text;
```

but you'll also need to change the `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach (ListViewItem cur in FolderList.Items)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you need a list of Directories into your batch file.

Then use: Directory.GetDirectories

```
private void HideItBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter hide = new StreamWriter(HideNameTxt.Text + ".bat");
    hide.WriteLine("@Echo off");
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\", "p*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (var dir in dirs)
    {
        hide.WriteLine("attrib " + dir + " +s +h");
     }
     hide.Close();
}
```